# Java' String replaceAll to replace overflow at front of string, not end.

Tags: java

I want to take in a string with dashes. Within the dashes there are groups of characters. That number of characters is specified by an integer K. I'm taking the dashes out to start so I have a clean String then I am using

```
replaceAll("(.{" + K + "})", "$0-")
```

To insert a - every K characters. I want the "overflow" (the left over characters after all previous characters were grouped to be put at the front of the string not the end).

For example I have a string with 8 characters:

```
String s = "1-23456-78";
String newS = s.replace("-", "");
```

newS is now 12345678

```
int K = 3; 
String newNewS = newS.replaceAll("(.{" + K + "})", "$0-").trim();
```

newNewS is 123-456-78

I want it to be 12-345-678. Anyway to reverse the replaceAll method or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could play with a lookahead ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZauT4z/1)):

```
.{3}(?=(?:.{3})*$)
```

Replace with:

```
-$0
```

In your case:

```java
"12345678".replaceAll(".{" + K + "}(?=(?:.{" + K + "})*$)", "-$0")
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Is there some documentation that you can point me to that explains lookahead well?

Comment: @PaulSender this website is a good resource for regexes: https://regular-expressions.mobi/lookaround.html?wlr=1

Answer (score 4):

One simple method I can think of is, you reverse the string and then apply the regex and then reverse again? Check this code.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String s = "1-23456-78";
    String newS = s.replace("-", "");
    System.out.println(newS);
    int K = 3;
    newS = new StringBuilder(newS).reverse().toString();
    String newNewS = newS.replaceAll("(.{" + K + "})", "$0-").trim();
    System.out.println(new StringBuilder(newNewS).reverse().toString());
}
```

Let me know if this sounds fine.

Comment: This would work but I want to avoid using String builder if I can. The look ahead method seems to work the cleanest.

Comment: @PaulSender: Sure, the other answer is definitely better as it only uses regex.

Comment: This was actually for some interview practice. Your solution would actually be better for that since companies are generally looking for how you go about solving problems and not the very exact way to solve the specific problem.